# How to make responsive columns with margins using bootsrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been trying to make a responsive navbar with columns but I can't manage to react well to the different sizes I've trying al lot of things: column-offset, contaniers, paddings... but I can't get a decent result. Here it is what I managed to do so far:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default ">

    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> 
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>



    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" style="height: 0px;">
    <div class="row show-grid">

        <div class=" col-xs-8 col-md-6 col-md-offset-2" > 
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="altre">
            <li><a href="#">Shop</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Style Guide</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Be a man</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class=" col-xs-4 col-md-4"> 

           <ul class="nav navbar-nav hidden-xs" id="login">
             <li class="dropdown">
               <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Login</a> 
               <div class="dropdown-menu">
                 <form class="navbar-form" role="form">
                   <p><input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="E-mail"></p>
                   <p><input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Contrasenya"></p>
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Log in</button>
                 </form>
               </div>
             </li>
           </ul>





           <form class="navbar-form text-center visible-xs" role="form">
             <p><input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="E-mail"></p>
             <p><input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Contrasenya"></p>
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Log in</button>
           </form>


       </div>
     </div>
      </div>

    </nav>
```

At first sight it seems to be working right but when you resize you see the difference between the right and left margin.

I'm very lost at this point, anyone knows a clean way to have a good result?

here the files if you don't want to download one by one:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwOBDBZckmYwZ20tLTRQdFI3a3c/edit?usp=sharing

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use .container class in divs before rows, the problem that you have seems to be using percentages in margin-left.

```
<div class="container"><!-- container -->
        <div class="row">
            <ul>...
        </div>
</div>
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/uFwnU/

Comment: I thought you couldn't put a container inside a row, thanks !!

Comment: Actually, is not inside the row, is outside :) the container contains :P, you're welcome.